# ngFor for complex nested JSON data in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor, async-pipe

I have a complex nested Json and in order to access deep to display on the View (HTML), what would be the code with ngFor? I am using Async Pipe. I want to get display value of the Longitudes\Latitudes. The data is 4 level nested as the following :

```
            JSON
                      {
                         "results": [
                                    {
                                      location": {
                                                 "postcode": "63104",
                                                 "coordinates": {
                                                     **"latitude": "-69.8246",
                                                     "longitude": "134.8719"**
                                                   }
                                        ] }}]}
              HTML
                <ul *ngIf="customerObs | async as response">     
                   <li *ngFor="let result of response.results">
                     {{????}}
                     </li> 
                   </ul>
             TS
            customerObs = this.http.get<Response>('https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json');
            constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Comment: `{{result.location.coordinates.latitude}}`  `{{result.location.coordinates.longitude}}`  ?

Comment: I have already tried it and it says "Property 'coordinates' does not exist on type 'Location'"

Comment: Can you share the model class which is used for your data?

Comment: Ah ! It has worked. I actually didn't import the interface "Location" in the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the JSON is nested, I had model interfaces and sub interfaces. The main Interface 'Result' needed 'Location' interface to be imported, I missed that initially. Once inported , it worked. Marked in **Bold** below :

```
           import { Id } from "./id";
           **import { Location } from "./location";**

              export interface Result {
                                  gender: string;   
                                  **location: Location;**
                                  email: string;    
                                  id: Id;     
                                   }
               export interface Location {    
                       coordinates: Coordinates;
                       timezone: Timezone;
                }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value nested.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of response.results">
    Longitude = {{ result.location.coordinates.longitude }}
    <br />
    Latitude = {{ result.location.coordinates.latitude }}
  </li>
</ul>
```